# Relation query from three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

there are three tables |users|family|relation

->User table.

```
|ID|Name|
|1 |max |
|2 |sam |
```

->family table.

```
|ID|UserID|FamilyMemberID|RelationID |
|1 |1     |       2       |    1     |
|2 |2     |       1       |     2    |
```

->Relation table

```
|ID| Name |
|1 |son   |
|2 |father|
```

i am trying to write a query to know who is who's son/father.

Plz help
thanks

Comment: what is `FamilyMemberID` ?

Comment: FamilyMemberID is the UserID of the family member. 
i am getting family member id using sql query like : select FamilyMemberID FROM family WHERE USERID = $id

Comment: now since i have tow id's ie. user id, and family member id. i need to determine the relationship get ID from relation table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not sure what exactly you need. If you are looking for the name of Father and Son of user in a single row, you can try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    u.name, 
    (SELECT name FROM user where id = father_relation.family_member_id) as 'Son Of',
    (SELECT name FROM user where id = son_relation.family_member_id) as 'Father Of'
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN family son_relation ON(u.id = son_relation.user_id and son_relation.relation_id = 1)
LEFT JOIN family father_relation ON(u.id = father_relation.user_id and father_relation.relation_id = 2)
```

Output:

```
| Name     | Son Of  | Father Of|
---------------------------------
| max      |         | sam      |
| sam      | max     |          |
```